# sending mail using telnet

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, telnet

I'm trying to send mail via the telnet command.  I've looked at several tutorials online to use `telnet <servername> 25`.  But I've tried `telnet mail.aol.com 25` and it gets stuck on `trying <ipAddress>....`  Is there something wrong with the syntax of my command?

Comment: It's quite possible that there is a firewall between you and the host that does not permit you connecting to port 25 from a residential IP. Many ISPs have such restrictions to avoid spam.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about Unix or Linux, it's about AOL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is right, but the port 25 is filtered on servers of mail.aol.com (there can be some firewall restrictions). Try to connect to some open server.

Comment: Which server would you suggest?  I'm just trying to get the command working at this point.

Comment: @bakalolo - Your question has nothing to do with U&L, about AOL, you'll need to research what server and how to use it somewhere else!